# How to have a key/value object pair with a function as a value that is executed only when the key is requested?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a javascript object that will return a result of a function once the key is accessed, but not before.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const mockTicker = {
    APPL: {
        symbol: 'APPLE',
        last: (() => (randomLastPrice(471.47, 817.63)))()
    }
```

So when I do this:

```
const fetch = mockTicker['APPL'] // { symbol: 'APPLE', last: 532.83}
```

This kind of works.

However, I can see that the function buried inside the `last` key is triggered every-time my code runs. I have a `console.log` statement inside the `randomLastPrice` and I can see that the function is executed the moment that object is assigned to the `mockTicker` variable.

Is there a way to attach a function to the `key=last` that is executed only whem we try to access that key? Probably like a lamda function as a concept?

So I would like to be able to do this:

```
let myTickerObject = mockTicker['APPL']; // This is the first time randomLastPrice(471.47, 817.63) is executed.
```

So we get a complete object as a return.

```
{ symbol: 'APPLE', timestamp: 1549137843213, last: 532.83 }
```

Here is a prototype: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/cryptoeraser/mhuojbpn/3/)

That returns:

```
{ symbol: "APPLE", timestamp: 1549138693551, last: Getter }
```

Comment: Why cannot `APPL` be a function that is executed when called?

Comment: I wanted this to follow the `let myTickerObject = mockTicker['APPL'];` convention. I think I have an idea how to do that now. The issues was that I needed to get the whole top level object with the evaluated internals. I'm trying to adapt the answers here and come up with a `getter` that will operate on the `APPL` key/val instead of the inner structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the application appears to be to return the last value of a ticker, instead of implementing an abstraction which eventually calls a function you can simply define each property of `mockTicker` as a function

```
const randomLastPrice = (a, b) => { 
  console.log('not called until now', a, b); return /* value */ 
};

const mockTicker = {
        APPL() {
          return {
             symbol: 'APPLE',
             last: randomLastPrice(471.47, 817.63)
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: This is returning a function. https://jsfiddle.net/cryptoeraser/ta93zgs8/3/

Comment: @symbolix Yes, call the function `let applCurr = mockTicker['APPL'](); console.log(applCurr['symbol'], applCurr['last'])` https://jsfiddle.net/fn61scvr/

Comment: Yeah. That works. Thanks. I guess it is not possible just to do `let curr = mockTicker['APPL']`?

Comment: @symbolix Why create unnecessary abstractions when ultimately the goal is to execute the function to get the latest value(s)?

Answer (score 3):

You might use a getter method, which runs only when the key is gotten, and when run, overwrites the getter with the randomized value, and returns that value:

```js
const mockTicker = {
  APPL: {
    symbol: 'APPLE',
    get last() {
      console.log('getting random number');
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'last', { value: Math.random() });
      return this.last;
    }
  }
}

console.log('start');
console.log(mockTicker.APPL.symbol);
console.log(mockTicker.APPL.last);
console.log(mockTicker.APPL.last);
```

Comment: Thanks, but with a named function `get last() { return randomLastPrice(2871.47, 3017.63); }` I am getting `last: [Getter]`?

Comment: Doesn't look like that to me - press "Run code snippet", in both the stack snippet console and in the browser console, it will display: `start \n APPLE \n getting random number \n <randnum> \n <randnum>`

Comment: I am not able to implement this solution using a named function. Let me see if I can get it to work. Your solution works %100. Just need to adapt it so it works with a named function, like in my original question.

Comment: Bracket vs dot notation makes no difference here (though dot notation is universally preferred when possible) - if you edit the snippet to use `['APPL']` instead, you'll see that the results are still as desired, no `last: [Getter]`.

Comment: Yes. It works here. In all cases. But not in my actual code. Maybe because it is a `node.js` script. I keep getting `last: [Getter]` :(

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] so we can reproduce and try to fix the problem?

Comment: Yes. I will link it to the end of the question.

Comment: I ran the snippet's code in Node and it has the same output as here, not sure what's going on

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I completely messed this up. I was requesting the main key `APPLE` and I was getting the whole sub-object as a  return value.